# How can i get single number exist in comma seprated string in mysql without find_in_set

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

Here is my column data:

Table Name: Employee

```
id  path
1   1,5,8,9,6,32,3
```

Now I need the Regexp query which will return true if specific number exist in  Path column.

Comment: why `without find_in_set` ?

Comment: i am working on elastic search and its not providing find_in_set. see the below link.
https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: This is a poorly designed table. Think about normalization.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `Employee` WHERE `path` REGEXP '(^|,)(1|5|8|9|6|32|3)(,|$)'
```

try this.